# How to correct configure grails on a ubuntu terminal?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have the following on my `.bashrc`:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
GRAILS_HOME="/root/grails"
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$GRAILS_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME
export GRAILS_HOME
export PATH
```

However, when I execute `> grails` in the terminal, I get:

```
root@localhost:~# grails
grails: JAVA_HOME is not a directory: /usr/bin/java
```

when I tried to replace to

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/share/java"
```

then the outcome is:

```
root@localhost:~# grails
grails: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly; can not execute: /usr/share/java/bin/java
```

what am I missing in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect `JAVA_HOME` to contain the `bin` directory containing `java` (and others).

So clearly those two options you've selected are not correct.

Looking at my Ubuntu installation, I have numerous Java packages under `/usr/lib/jvm`, and I would select an appropriate one there e.g.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: should I use double quotes around JAVA_HOME=""?

Comment: You shouldn't have to quote that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to source the changed file eg: $ source [filename of the changes made] in your example .bashrc